# image and text for nav bar button item. swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I saw the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474257/1334575) for adding an image to the left nav bar item. And I did it successfully.

But I also want to add a small text next to the image. For example I want to show how many coins the user have. So I need to show a coins image and the number of coins next to it. How can it be done?

I tried to set title (with "123"), but I only see the image and not the title. This my code:

```
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "coins.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.callMethod), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    button.setTitle("123", for: UIControlState.normal)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Since the bar button item is initialized with a custom view, you can add a `UIImage` and a `UILabel` to one view, along with a `UIButton` to capture the touch event, and pass that into the initializer.

```
    // the UIButton is simply there to capture touch up event on the entire bar button view.
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "coins")
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 35, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30))
    label.text = "1234"
    let buttonView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 30))
    button.frame = buttonView.frame
    buttonView.addSubview(button)
    buttonView.addSubview(imageView)
    buttonView.addSubview(label)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: buttonView)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

You might have to adjust the frames accordingly for your own uses, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the width it's 30 try to make it bigger like 50

```
let buttonContainer:UIView = UIView()
buttonContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 32)

let image = UIImage(named: "coins")

let button = UIButton.init(type: .system)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.frame = buttonContainer.frame
button.setTitle("sss", for: .normal)      
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

buttonContainer.addSubview(button)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonContainer)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use backgroundImage for image and setTitle for test to the button. 
follow this link definitely you will get idea:**

[image for nav bar button item swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473359/image-for-nav-bar-button-item-swift/48658610#48658610)

Answer (score -2):

Use `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems` that is an array of `UIBarButtonItem`

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem()
let text = UIBarButtonItem()

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [button, text]
```